# Pandas rolling cumulative sum of across two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, sum, rolling-computation

I'm looking to create a rolling grouped cumulative sum across two dataframes. I can get the result via iteration, but wanted to see if there was a more intelligent way.

I need the 5 row block of A to roll through the rows of B and accumulate.  Think of it as rolling balance with a block of contributions and rolling returns.

So, here's the calculation for C

```
    A           B                           
1   100.00      1   0.01        101.00                  
2   110.00      2   0.02        215.22  102.00              
3   120.00      3   0.03        345.28  218.36  103.00          
4   130.00      4   0.04        494.29  351.89  221.52  104.00      
5   140.00      5   0.05        666.00  505.99  358.60  224.70  105.00  
                6   0.06                684.75  517.91  365.38  227.90  106.00
                7   0.07                        703.97  530.06  372.25  231.12
                8   0.08                                723.66  542.43  379.21
                9   0.09                                        743.85  555.04
                10  0.10                                                 764.54




C Row 5         
        
Begining Balance    Contribution    Return  Ending Balance
            0.00     100.00         0.01    101.00
          101.00     110.00         0.02    215.22
          215.22     120.00         0.03    345.28
          345.28     130.00         0.04    494.29
          494.29     140.00         0.05    666.00
        
C Row 6         
        
Begining Balance    Contribution    Return  Ending Balance
            0.00    100.00          0.02    102.00
          102.00    110.00          0.03    218.36
          218.36    120.00          0.04    351.89
          351.89    130.00          0.05    505.99
          505.99    140.00          0.06    684.75
```

Here's what the source data looks like:

```
    A           B
1   100.00      1   0.01
2   110.00      2   0.02
3   120.00      3   0.03
4   130.00      4   0.04
5   140.00      5   0.05
                6   0.06
                7   0.07
                8   0.08
                9   0.09
                10  0.10
```

Here is the desired result:

```
    C
1   Nan
2   Nan
3   Nan
4   Nan
5   666.00
6   684.75
7   703.97
8   723.66
9   743.85
10  764.54
```

Comment: Please do include your data as text, not images.

Comment: Apologies - first question, I thought the images would come through.